# What is the difference between New-DfsnFolder and New-DfsnFolderTarget?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, dfs

What is the difference between New-DfsnFolder and New-DfsnFolderTarget?

Both commands require both parameters, `-Path` and `-TargetPath`. They create the same thing. A DFS folder with a target.

So what is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below for details and examples.  `New-DfsnFolder` will create a new folder, while `New-DfsnFolderTarget` will add a **target** to an *existing* DFS namespace folder.

Sources: [New-DfsnFolder](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj884271.aspx) & [New-DfsnFolderTarget](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj884280.aspx)

---

`New-DfsnFolder`  - Creates a folder in a DFS namespace.

> The `New-DfsnFolder` cmdlet creates a folder in a Distributed File
>   System (DFS) namespace. Specify the path and a path for a folder
>   target for the new folder. A DFS namespace folder has one or more
>   folder targets that are shared folders on computers. When a client
>   attempts to connect to a folder, the DFS namespace server provides a
>   list of folder targets, called referrals. The server determines the
>   order for referrals and clients attempt to connect to a folder target
>   in the order that the server provides. You can specify settings for
>   the new folder. You can use this cmdlet to enable or disable the
>   following settings:
>
> - In-site referrals.
> - Target failback.
>
> You can also add a descriptive comment, select the state of the folder and
>   folder target, and set the Time to Live (TTL)
>   interval for referrals.
>
> Finally, you can specify the priority class
>   and priority rank for referrals.

The command below **creates** a folder called `LegacySoftware` in the `\\Contoso\AccountingResources` namespace. The folder target is `\\Contoso-FS\AccountingLegacy`. The command enables target failback for the folder. The command includes a description for the new folder.

```
PS C:\> New-DfsnFolder -Path "\\Contoso\AccountingResources\LegacySoftware" -TargetPath "\\Contoso-FS\AccountingLegacy" -EnableTargetFailback $True -Description "Folder for legacy software."
```

---

`New-DfsnFolderTarget` - Adds a target to a DFS namespace folder.

> The `New-DfsnFolderTarget` cmdlet adds a target to a Distributed File
>   System (DFS) namespace folder. Specify the DFS namespace folder and
>   the folder target. You can set the state of the DFS namespace target
>   and configure priority class and priority rank for referrals.
>
> A DFS
>   namespace folder has one or more folder targets that are shared
>   folders on computers. When a client attempts to connect to a folder,
>   the DFS namespace server provides a list of folder targets, called
>   referrals. The server determines the order for referrals and clients
>   attempt to connect to a folder target in the order that the server
>   provides.

The command below **adds** `\\Contoso-FS\Software` as a target for the DFS namespace folder `\\Contoso\AccountingResources\LegacySoftware` with a referral priority of global low.

```
PS C:\> New-DfsnFolderTarget -Path "\\Contoso\AccountingResources\LegacySoftware" -TargetPath "\\Contoso-FS\Software" -ReferralPriorityClass GlobalLow
```

Comment: To an *existing* DFS folder? Oh man, I never thought about that and New-DfsnFolderTarget does exactly the same as New-DfsnFolder, there is no *existing* DFS folder … and that confused me, I guess. Thank you.